# Create a PySpark .when() statement with any number of clauses

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to PySpark and I'm trying to create a generic `.when()` function, that can accept any number of when-clauses without me having to list them in the function.

The hope is to drive this from some sort of data-structure, so generalising a function of the form:

```py
(
    df.when(
        df.value == 1, 'one'
    ).when(
        df.value == 2, 'two'
    ).when(
        df.N == N, 'N'
    )
)
```

Into something like:

```py
(
    df.when(
       **when_clauses
    )
)
```

I suspect I will have to make use of `**kwargs` to allow this to happen, but I'm unsure if Spark already supports this sort of behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for `df.replace`. It replaces in place, so if you want to keep the original column, you can duplicate it using `df.withColumn('value2', 'value')`.

```
mapping = {1: 'one', 2: 'two', ...}

df.replace(mapping)
```

Comment: thank you for this, I was unaware of replace - I've upvoted; will allow others to answer before marking this off.

Comment: this seems to error out, as the types are going from int to str: `ValueError: Mixed type replacements are not supported`

Comment: `df.select('*', F.col('value').cast('string').alias('value2')).replace({'1': 'one', '2': 'two'})`